# Why isn't a transaction active after a cursor is created but before it is exhausted?

Tags: python, sqlite

Consider the following code:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE t1 (col1, col2, col3);')
conn.commit()
rows = [(k+1, k+2, k+3) for k in range(1000)]
conn.executemany('INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (?, ?, ?);', rows)
conn.commit()
curs = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM t1;')
next(curs)
print(conn.in_transaction)
```

For me this prints `False`, while my expectation is that it would return `True`, because I have not traversed all of the rows from the `SELECT`, which means that the statement has not fully executed. I didn't issue an explicit `BEGIN`. I know that in such cases the behavior depends on `conn.isolation_level`, but from what I understand [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions), this attribute is only relevant when DML statements are issued. Does this mean that for all other statements when you execute them without an explicit `BEGIN`, an implicit transaction is opened? (i.e. that for non-DML statements we are in autocommit mode always) Maybe `conn.in_transaction` returns `True` only when in explicit transactions, but returns `False` when in implicit ones? If my `SELECT` started an implicit transaction I know it must be active because such transactions are automatically committed only when the last cursor closes (see [Implicit versus explicit transactions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)), but I still have a cursor opened.

EDIT: There is another issue. I am free to make and commit changes to the database before my cursor is done (If you run the code below after the code above, it prints `(-1, -2, -3)`, even if my `SELECT` was executed before the update)

```py
conn.execute('UPDATE t1 SET col1=-1, col2=-2, col3=-3 WHERE col1=3')
conn.commit()
next(curs)
print(next(curs))
```

I would expect `(3, 4, 5)` to be printed, as that was the relation before the update. Is my expectation wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.in_transaction) [*emphasis added*]

> **in_transaction**
>
> True if a transaction is active (*there are uncommitted changes*), False otherwise. Read-only attribute.

Read literally, since a SELECT never has *uncommitted changes*, the attribute would never be *True*. Further `in_transaction` is a connection attribute, not a cursor attribute.

Comment: A SELECT does begin a (read) transaction in SQLite. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Comment: New and improved answer posted.

Comment: I know that ```in_transaction``` is a connection attribute. But from the SQLite docs we see that "An implicit transaction (a transaction that is started automatically, not a transaction started by BEGIN) is committed automatically when the last active statement finishes. _A statement finishes when its last cursor closes_, ..." I know that the cursors of Python are not the same as the internal cursors of SQLite, but there must be a connection between them, and I guess that with an inexhausted Python cursor the SQLite cursors are also not closed.

Comment: It is clear to me from the doc that `in_transaction` will return False in this code snippet because there are no uncommitted changes. It is also consistent with "_when the last active statement finishes_" if one considers `next(curs)` the last active statement. Since the result is what I expect based on my interpretation, I'm sticking to it :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am curious though: do you think this is a poorly named attribute? Because the connection _is_ in a transaction after executing a ```SELECT```. The quote _"when the last active statement finishes"_ is from the SQLite docs not from the Python docs. By _"statement"_ it is meant SQL statement, not Python statement.

Comment: That question is _way_ above my pay grade.

Comment: I am _much_ more inclined to believe it is aptly named but that I am not understanding something (which is probably obvious). I made an edit to the question which probably provides hints to my misunderstandings.

Comment: Re the edit: those are the results I would expect. If you need to keep the original column values, perhaps implement with `fetchall()` instead of iterating over cursor. This example  confirms my suspicion that _execute_ method doesn't actually fetch the rows. It returns a "cursor object" and another operation is always required to "see" the data.